Question about Mannat (conditional vow)
Salam, I have a question about "Mannat"(conditional vow). I have done a "Mannat" of "Sadkah" to succeed in a work without analyzing. I didn't know it is not a good thing to do conditional vows. After realizing that this "sadaqah" is not practical for me and extremely difficult to do, I want to break the "Mannat". Now is there any procedure to do it?
FYKI, I didn't succeed yet on that work. It has a 50-50 chance to succeed.
